# How to calculate day light saving time using R

Tags: r, dplyr, dst

I want to calculate the daylight saving time beginning date for each year from 2003
through 2021 and keep only the days that are 60 days before and after the daylight saving time begin date each
year.

I.e date will change each year (falls on a Sunday) and moved from happening in April 2003-2006 to happening in March during the years 2007-2021.

I need to create a running variable `days` that measures the distance from the daylight saving time begin date for each year with
`days=0` on the first day of daylight saving time.

[Here's dataset](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1GrEDQWzFYU4f-4O4ZsF54NH53dBJymvy/view?usp=sharing)

```
year    month   day propertycrimes  violentcrimes
2003      1      1     94                  34
2004      1      1     60                  46
2005      1      1     106                 41
2006      1      1     87                  40
2007      1      1     72                  36
2008      1      1     43                  50
2009      1      1     35                  32
2010      1      1     32                  50
2011      1      1     29                  45
2012      1      1     32                  45
```

Here's my code so far

```
library(readr)
dailycrimedataRD <- read_csv("dailycrimedataRD.csv")
View(dailycrimedataRD)
days <- .POSIXct(month, tz="GMT")
```

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61550077/r-get-daylight-saving-beginning-and-ending-from-year) should get you started.

Answer (score 0):

I would use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61550196/8465924) answer following @jlhoward kindly suggestion and making some arrangements for further convenience:

```
library(lubridate)

get_dst2 <- function(y = 2019, tz = "CET"){
 start <- paste0(y, '-01-01')
 end <- paste0(y, '-12-31')
 d1 <- seq(
      as.POSIXct(start, tz = tz),
      as.POSIXct(end, tz =tz), 
      by = "hour")
 data.frame(
       year = y,
       spring_shift = range(d1[lubridate::dst(d1)])[1],
       autumn_shift = range(d1[lubridate::dst(d1)])[2],
       stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
}
```

Note that the `get_dst2()` generates a date sequence for each requested year with hourly resolution which may take quite a while. That is why a solution with `merge()` is beneficial.

Let's generate a data frame for the whole years range

```
dls_shifts_df <- do.call(rbind, lapply(X = 2003:2021, get_dst2))
```

And just merge this data frame with the original `data`:

```
data <- read.table(text = 
"year    month   day propertycrimes  violentcrimes
2003      1      1     94                  34
2004      1      1     60                  46
2005      1      1     106                 41
2006      1      1     87                  40
2007      1      1     72                  36
2008      1      1     43                  50
2009      1      1     35                  32
2010      1      1     32                  50
2011      1      1     29                  45
2012      1      1     32                  45",
     header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

res_ds <- merge(data, dls_shifts_df)
```

Finally, we have to parse the original data into a proper data-time format, calculate distance to spring and autumn time shifts and make a proper subsetting (an 85-days threshold is used instead of 60 days according to data availability in the `data` sample):

```
res_ds[, "date"] <- parse_date_time(
    paste(res_ds$year, res_ds$month, res_ds$day, sep = "-"),
    "ymd",
    tz = "CET")
res_ds$dist_to_spr_shift <- res_ds$date - res_ds$spring_shift
res_ds$dist_to_aut_shift <- res_ds$date - res_ds$autumn_shift
# we are interested in a shift closest to the current date
res_ds$days_to_shift <- apply(cbind(abs(res_ds$dist_to_spr_shift), abs(res_ds$dist_to_aut_shift)), 1, FUN = min)
res_ds[res_ds$days_to_shift <= 85, ]
```

**NB** A small performance test shows why the `merge` approach seems to be preferable as compared with a direct column addition with results of the `get_dst()` function call:

```
ds_tau_compar <- microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
 merge = merge(data, dls_shifts_df),
 add_column = lapply(FUN = function(Z) get_dst(Z)[1], X = data$year),
 times = 1000L
)
ggplot2::autoplot(ds_tau_compar)
```

[image]